# What is the length limit for BLE characteristics?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, characteristics

I am reading the Bluetooth Core Spec. v 4.2 document, but I can't find any information about the characteristic length limit.

- **What is the length limit for characteristic of BLE services?**

Answer (score 6):

The limit is set by what is possible for an attribute value, see the ATT part (Vol 3, Part F, 3.2.9):

> The maximum length of an attribute value shall be 512 octets.

You should also consider what could be sent in one packet, which is 20 bytes (ATT_MTU - 3). With 20 bytes or less you can use simple transfer procedures and save power.

Comment: The default MTU is 20 and this value can be changed to max 512, then the GATT value can be set as 512-3 byte. use 20 bytes or less does not save power actually if you want to transfer byte more than 20.